# Why single quotes in converting to Question mark in jsp?

Tags: java, html, jsp, meta-tags

In Jsp If I write something with single quotes then its saved as single quotes. But If I copy text from doc then Its replaced by question mark. for example 
swimmer’s  became swimmer?s . 
can any one tell me why its happening? Is there any charter format need to set in content type. I have tried using utf-8 and iso-8859-1.

Comment: The single quote might be one of those stylized quotes with a separate code, and may not be recognized in the paste target.

Comment: so how can we handle this type of situation

Comment: could you please provide me such type of example?

Comment: Whoops! Sorry. The second comment I posted above was for a different question. Make sure the original document is using normal quotes, or allow the target to handle the weird quotes.